# how to pass a variable to cmd in python

Tags: python

I am trying to export the list of data stage jobs into xml format using python.

my code looks like as below

```
  
import os
import io

DSJobList = r'C:\Users\kulkap10\Downloads\Datastage\JobList\datastage_joblist.txt'
ProjectName = 'CBMODS_SIT1'

DSJobListHandler = open (DSJobList, "r")

for JobName in DSJobListHandler.readlines():
    os.chdir(r'C:\Program Files\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic')
    print("Job Export Start " + JobName)
    os.system('cmd /k "dsexport.exe /D=auirvtqtg007:9443 /U=kulkap10 /P=Happyvalentines$14 /JOB=JobName     CBMODS_SIT1  /NODEPENDENTS /XML    C:\\dsexport\\JobName.xml"')
    #os.system('cmd /k "dsexport.exe"')
    #print(JobName + "Ended Export")
    print("Directory changed " +JobName)
```

The jobname is supposed to be the value of the content in the file however the cmd command is not getting the value and literally taking "jobname" as a value and executing it

thank you for your help

edited from the original post as the original issue is resolved

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I am able to identify the issue regarding unicode error as it is to do with the path that starting with C:\Users. so changed path to C:\dsexport\JobName.xml  but getting another error  "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: this issue is resolved